# package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart': Failed assertion: line 2297 pos 15: 'heightFactor == null || heightFactor >= 0.0': is not true

Tags: flutter

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 6,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: groupedTransactionValues.map((data) {
            return Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.tight,
              child: ChartBar(
                data['day'],
                data['amount'],
                (data['amount'] as double) / totalSpending,
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: dose your data have an item which is null, like all fields inside an item being null?

Comment: can you try by wrapping Flexible with Expanded widget ?

Answer (score 12):

Change this:

```
(data['amount'] as double) / totalSpending
```

to this:

```
totalSpending == 0 ? 0 : (data["amount"] as double) / totalSpending
```

This error occurs when your transaction list is empty. If your transaction list is empty dart evaluates that expression as 0 / 0 which is NaN. When you pass this NaN to the ChartBar heightFactor: spendingPctOfTotal it throws that error because heightFactor is expecting a value bigger then 0 or null (NaN is different from null).

Comment: I am amazed by this answer, not only it helped me fix my issue but also it is using the same variable names I am now using.

it should be from Flutter tutorial by Maximilian Schwarzmüller. as i am also from his tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually because of you are trying to divide it with 0.So,just change the line of

`(data['amount'] as double) / totalSpending`

to this

```
totalSpending == 0 ? 0 : (data["amount"] as double) / totalSpending
```

If you have the problem says that "A RenderFlex overflowed by 36 pixels on the bottom."

Just change this:

```
child: Container(
    height: 30,
    child: Row(
        children: groupedTransactionValues.map((data) {
      return ChartBar(
          data['day'],
          data['amount'],
          totalSpending == 0.0
              ? 0.0
              : (data['amount'] as double) / totalSpending);
    }).toList()),
  )
```

to this:

```
child: Container(
    height: 100,
    child: Row(
        children: groupedTransactionValues.map((data) {
      return ChartBar(
          data['day'],
          data['amount'],
          totalSpending == 0.0
              ? 0.0
              : (data['amount'] as double) / totalSpending);
    }).toList()),
  )
```

Thats all, hope you can solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I am also taking that course and came to the same issue.

You need to pass the recent transactions into the chart like this:

```
List<Transaction> get _recentTransactions {
    return _transactions.where((tx) => DateTime.now().difference(tx.date).inDays <= 7).toList();
}
```

and then use this in your build:

```
Chart(transactions: _recentTransactions);
```